# ENOENT error when using fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, fs

Trying to write to a file using fs.writeFile into a sibling directory. This works fine when using `Sitemap.xml` into the same directory, but not with the relative path. The `public` directory exists and it gives the same error whether or not `Sitemap.xml` exists.

Relevant dir structure:

```
/public
   Sitemap.xml
   app files
/create-sitemap
    index.js - file containing code below
app.js
```

---

```
fs.write('../public/Sitemap.xml', data.toString(), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Wrote sitemap to XML");
});


Toms-MacBook-Pro:moviehunter tomchambers$ node create-sitemap/index.js

/Users/tomchambers/projects/project/create-sitemap/index.js:88
        if (err) throw err;
                       ^
Error: ENOENT, open '../public/Sitemap.xml'
```

Comment: How does your project folder structure look like?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you use relative paths in node, they're related to the node process. So, if you run your script like `node create-sitemap/index.js` from the `/Users/tomchambers/projects/project/` directory, it'll look for the `/Users/tomchambers/projects/public/Sitemap.xml` file, which doesn't exist.

In your case, you could use the `__dirname` global variable, that returns,  [as the docs say](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname):

> The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.

So your code should looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

fs.write(path.join(__dirname, '../public/Sitemap.xml'), data.toString(), function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Wrote sitemap to XML");
});
```

Comment: I recommend using `process.chdir()` to change your app's working directory to __dirname (or a more useful path, if for example using asar).  This will allow you to use relative paths without any extra fuss.

Comment: I was facing this error when I tried to generate `fileName` using `path.join('abc', '.', 'pdf')` which put a `'/'` before and after the `'.'` character. Hope this comment helps somebody

Comment: This saved my day. One note is to make sure where you call the path, if you are in a subdirectory make sure to take that in consideration.

Answer (score 10):

For me the problem was that the given filename contained unallowed characters on Windows.

Specifically, I tried adding a timestamp to the name e.g. `10:23:11` and the `:` were not allowed which caused this error.

Comment: Woohoo, thanks! I was stumped as to why it was not working on WIndows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was trying to write the file in a path that did not exist. so make sure you create the folders to write in them.